# Using Shared Preferences to save numbers in EditText

Tags: java, android, memory, sharedpreferences, calculator

I am new to android programming and I created a simple calculator. I want the user to be able to pause the application without losing the numbers entered in the two EditText boxes. I am trying to use shared preferences but for some reason my app keeps crashing. How can I fix this?

```
package com.example.simplecalculator;

import android.os.Bundle;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.simplecalculator.*;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
public static final String MYPREFERENCES = "MyPreferences_001";
float answer;
final EditText numberone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number1);
final EditText numbertwo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number2);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mySharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MYPREFERENCES, 0);
    String number1 = mySharedPreferences.getString("number1", null);
    String number2 = mySharedPreferences.getString("number2", null);
    numberone.setText(number1); 
    numbertwo.setText(number2);



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void Addition(View view) {

answer = Float.parseFloat(numberone.getText().toString()) + Float.parseFloat(numbertwo.getText().toString());;

TextView value = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer);
value.setText("Your sum is " + answer);


}

public void Subtraction(View view) {

answer = Float.parseFloat(numberone.getText().toString()) - Float.parseFloat(numbertwo.getText().toString());;

TextView value = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer);
value.setText("Your difference is " + answer);

}


public void Multiplication(View view) {
    answer = Float.parseFloat(numberone.getText().toString()) * Float.parseFloat(numbertwo.getText().toString());;

TextView value = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer);
value.setText("Your product is " + answer);

}

public void Division(View view) {

    answer = Float.parseFloat(numberone.getText().toString()) / Float.parseFloat(numbertwo.getText().toString());;

TextView value = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer);
value.setText("Your quotient is " + answer);

}

public void Power(View view) {
    answer = (float) Math.pow(Float.parseFloat(numberone.getText().toString()), Float.parseFloat(numbertwo.getText().toString()));

TextView value = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer);
value.setText("Your answer is " + answer);

}

public void Root(View view) {

    answer = (float) Math.sqrt(Float.parseFloat(numberone.getText().toString()));

TextView value = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer);
value.setText("Your answer is " + answer);

}


public void onPause(){

    mySharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MYPREFERENCES, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = mySharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("number1", numberone.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("number2", numbertwo.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();

}

}
```

Comment: You probably getting NumberFormatException.

Comment: What is that and how do I fix it? Sorry once again I'm new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application is crashing because you are trying to initializing your view before setting any layout to your activity. Now, initialize the as follows...your problem will be solved.

```
EditText numberone;
EditText numbertwo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    numberone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number1);
    numbertwo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number2);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
final EditText numberone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number1);
final EditText numbertwo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number2);
```

Keep that inside onCreate(), after `setContentView()`

Also, 
What happens the first time, when nothing is stored in sharedPref,

```
String number1 = mySharedPreferences.getString("number1", null);
    String number2 = mySharedPreferences.getString("number2", null);
```

return some value then instead of "null" .

If using SharedPref pretty often for a Calculator app, i suggest making a function for get and put the sharedPref..
Something like:

```
public static void saveDataToPreferences(String key,
            String value) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("your package name",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }
    public static String getDataFromPreferences(String key) {

        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("your package name",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return prefs.getString(key, Constants.BLANK);
    }
```

If the functions are inside your activity, the context for that activity can be declared globally. Else pass that in the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

You have initilize your `EditText` before `onCreate` do that inside `onCreate`

```
float answer;
final EditText numberone;
final EditText numbertwo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         numberone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number1);
         numbertwo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting NULL Pointer exception most probably. Its because at first when your application sharedprefrences doesn't have any thing, you tend to access it and get a value from it and when its not present you set value of string NULL. When you try to show that value which is NULL on the screen, it crashes.
Do this:

```
String number1 = mySharedPreferences.getString("number1", "");
String number2 = mySharedPreferences.getString("number2", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use [onSaveInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) and [onRestoreInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) for this purpose.

It's used when the Activity is forcefully terminated by`activity is destroyed due to normal app behavior, such as when the user presses the Back button or your activity signals its own destruction by calling finish()`  or `the OS (ex: when your Activity is in the background and another task needs resources)`  . When this happens, onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outstate) will be called and it's up to your app to add any state data you want to save in outstate.

When the user resumes your Activity, onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) gets called and savedInstanceState will be non-null if your Activity was terminated in a scenario described above. Your app can then grab the data from savedInstanceState and regenerate your Activity's state to how it was when the user last saw it.

Basically in onCreate, when savedInstanceState is null, then it means this is a 'fresh' launch of your Activity. And when it's non-null (if your app saved the data in onSaveInstanceState(...), it means the Activity state needs to be recreated.

[**Here**](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) is much more detail about it